# Do "natural weapons" count as being unarmed?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, natural-weapon, unarmed-combat, werewolf-the-forsaken

One of the Uratha in our pack has the first dot of the Unarmed Defense merit:

From God Machine Chronicles, p65:

> **Like a Book (*):** ... When facing an unarmed opponent and not Dodging, increase your character's Defense by half of his Brawl (round down).

Does a werewolf using claws or teeth (in an appropriate form) count as being unarmed? Does a spirit that attacks with claws count as unarmed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. A character using natural weapons like claws or fangs is fighting using Unarmed Combat (using the Brawl skill) and so counts as an unarmed opponent. (See the description of a spear, which offers +1 Defense against an opponent who is unarmed or using a weapon of Size 1.)